# Can I set html type to the subject of mail using swift?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I would like to set html type of subject using SwiftMailer. I know I can use `$message->setContentType('text/html')` for the body but is it possible to set html type of subject like this?

Answer (score 0):

The 'subject' is a header field...

Actually you can put (almost) anything into the subject, but it will only be interpreted as text.